# How to Compare two files and then append line that is not a partial match?

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I am trying to compare two files (`Extensions.txt` and `Temp.txt`). If there is a line that does not partially match from `Extensions.txt` in `Temp.txt` I would like to append the missing line to `Temp.txt`.

`Extensions.txt` (Very basic, one column):

```
111
1234
4321
```

`Temp.txt`:

```
1234/sip:1234@192.168.1.10:5060  9421b96c5e   Avail   1.480
4321/sip:4321@192.168.1.11:5060  e9b6b979a4   Avail   1.855
```

Basically, what I want to do is find a match based on everything before the `/` in the first column and if there is no match, I would like to print the non matching line to the bottom of the file so that it would end up like this:

```
1234/sip:1234@192.168.1.10:5060  9421b96c5e   Avail   1.480
4321/sip:4321@192.168.1.11:5060  e9b6b979a4   Avail   1.855
111
```

So far I have attempted `grep -v` and it doesn't produce the results that I want, I also tried with `awk` and it seems like that is the way to go, however I do not have a full understanding of how `awk` works in order to produce the appropriate results.

Comment: If there is a row in 'Temp.txt' like `1235/...` (no match in the first file) will it be in the output or not?

Comment: If a value in the extensions.txt file is not found in temp.txt it will output the missing value from extensions to temp. If that makes sense, if not let me know.

Comment: So, you mean that, in the opposite case, if value in temp.txt is missing from extensions.txt, you don't want it into the output at all.

Comment: If  a partial match of the value in Extensions.txt is found in Temp.txt, I don't want to print/output anything. I want to output the non-found "Extension" value if not found, which in the case of the example above would be 111.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can parse the files with `awk`

```bsh
awk -F '/' '
    FNR == NR {seen[$1] = $0; next}
    {if ($1 in seen) print seen[$1]; else missing[$1]}
    END {for (x in missing) print x}
' Temp.txt Extensions.txt
```

Output:

```
1234/sip:1234@192.168.1.10:5060 9421b96c5e Avail 1.480
4321/sip:4321@192.168.1.11:5060 e9b6b979a4 Avail 1.855
111
```

- Set field separator to slash, `-F '/'`
- The action after `FNR == NR` is executed for the lines of the first input file. We store the lines in the associative array `seen` as keys, and go to `next` line.
- The second action is executed for the second file, when `FNR != NR`. If the first field matches, we print the stored line, `else` we save the field into another array `missing`.
- At the `END`, we print the missing lines.

Comment: I selected this one as best answer compared to the previous. The reason being is this only outputs the missing value and not all plus the missing value. Thanks Again!

Comment: Please keep the "accepted" to the initial answer, as both work.

Comment: While both work and the other answer is great as well, I do find that you were the fastest to answer and ultimately the most helpful, so I believe you deserve the "accepted".

Comment: Just realized something and was just wondering what your thoughts are. When running awk with the two input files, it seems that even if 1234 is found in Extension.txt and Temp.txt it still prints the value 1234. Any ideas?

Comment: If you have a specific example case, I could further see it. For now, this script parses the `Temp.txt` first, so if `1234/...` is found there, then it will print the matching line and not the number alone, for any occurence of `1234` in `Extensions.txt`

Comment: sorry, could you have `12345/` and still want to match `1234`? a partial match in the first field?

Answer (score 3):

You could read the contents of `Extensions.txt` into an array, delete the partial matches, then print whatever remains:

```
$ awk -F/ '
    NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} {for(i in a) if($1 ~ i) delete a[i]} END{for(i in a) print i} 1
  ' Extensions.txt Temp.txt
1234/sip:1234@192.168.1.10:5060  9421b96c5e   Avail   1.480
4321/sip:4321@192.168.1.11:5060  e9b6b979a4   Avail   1.855
111
```

Comment: Nice one. I think `{for(i in a) if($1 ~ i) delete a[i]}` is the same as `$1 in a {delete a[$1]}`, right?

Comment: This worked amazing!  Thank you so much!

Comment: This will also print lines from `Temp.txt` that has no match in `Extensions.txt` (see discussion in comments). I just guess that `Temp.txt` (first fields of it) is a subset of `Extensions.txt`, although this was not stated.

Comment: But now I see "append the missing line to Temp.txt" which is the opposite, so you do want to print them (if existed), as said, I guess it is a always a subset, that's why both parsing seem good to OP.

Comment: @Quasímodo `$1 in a` would work fine for *complete* matches; `for(i in a) if($1 ~ i)` will catch *partial* (regex) matches, which is what the OP asks for - although it's not clear if it's actually what they want.

Comment: @MSTekMTL if you do want a partial match, like `1234` to match the line `12345/...` from `temp`, please use (and accept) this answer, I have to modify mine with a loop like here for partial match, I use full match of the first field.

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep`+`cut`:

```
grep -xvFf <(cut -d'/' -f1 tmp) ext >> tmp
```

---

Here we are safe in `grep` using `tmp` for the input in process-substitution as the patterns feed and write the result back into same `tmp` file in append mode;  see the explanation in below link:

[Using same filename for the input in sub-shell and also as output in parent shell will conflict?](/a/619811/72456)

Answer (score 0):

Also can use `join`.

```
join -t"/" -a1 -e " " -o '1.1,2.1,2.2' <(awk '{ print $1"/"}' Extension.txt ) <( awk '{ print $0}' Text.txt)
```